# Running camera v2 with no binning and resolution 640*480

Tags: camera

I want to run the camera v2(IMX219, 1.12um pixel) with no binning and resolution 640x480. Camera mode 7 provide a resolution 640x480, but with 2x2 binning. Inspecting the I2C bus reveals the the binning is set to mode 3: x2 analog binning. Camera mode 1,2 and 3 have no binning but they have a low frame rate. Is it possible to have the high framerate of mode 7 but with no binning?